# How to share a software product having multiple microservices and with specific Kubernetes configurations

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

I am new to Kubernetes. I have a doubt.

Say I have a software product which has 5 Microservices. It is deployed on my Kubernetes cluster (OCP Cluster) and it is working fine. Each microservice has Kubernetes configuration files on cluster - deployment, service, configmap yaml files etc.

Suppose I want to sell the product to customers and they will setup in their own prod Kubernetes cluster (May be in OCP or Amazon EKS etc)

**Which is the appropriate way to give the product to the customers?**

**Way1** - Sending all the yaml files (deployment.yaml, service.yaml, configmap.yaml) for each microservice. As total 5 Microservices so 5 deployment.yaml, 5 service.yaml, configMap.yaml files etc. Upon receiving those files they will manually setup the files in their Kubernetes cluster and then all the pods will come up.

**Way2** - For each microservice we will give the Kubernetes Helm chart. So total 5 Helm Charts for 5 Microservices. Upon receiving the charts they will install all the yaml files with helm install.

**Way3** - Or any other better way?

Note- Private Docker Image Repository access will be given to the customers for pulling the microservice images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way 1: No. There is tooling to do this. You shouldn't need to send yaml files around.

Way 2: This is the best way but with some edits. Create 5 helm charts that manage the separate components of your product. Then create a 6th chart that depends on the other 5. This way you only have to give 1 "product" chart to the consumer and that chart then pulls everything it needs to run. This is usually how its done. See projects like [loki-stack](https://github.com/grafana/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/loki-stack/requirements.yaml) from grafana. They have a helm chart called 'loki-stack' and that chart has dependencies on grafana, loki, Prometheus, promtail etc. Your consumers will then just `helm install my-product` and helm will take care of getting the 5 service charts.

Way 3: There are many ways to do this but they are all kind of specific to implementations. For example you can use OAM + KubeVela. However if a consumer doesn't use OAM + KubeVela its a problem. IMO Helm is the standard approach fow now until more people start using stuff like KubeVela

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation with the example.

Comment: So I have to give all the 6 (5+1) helm charts to them and they will just install 1 helm chart which has dependencies for other 5 helm charts. Right?